Generating at compile time a multipage localized web application
I want to create a simple website / MPA using typescript, html and tailwind. I did not want to use any flashy framework as I do not really need it. The application is pretty small. I would like to use a templating engine to write the static content (html, css). I do not want the template to do conditional logic. I only want to use simple stuff to cut down dev time. I want to support my content in multiple languages. Ideally I would like to have one single html page and output multiple html files all with the correct translated content. So, let's assume I have an index.html file. I use some templating engine and I do something like { title }. Then, using some kind of tool I am able to use some resource files (json files containing translations) and output multiple html files like this en/index.html, es/index.html etc.... I am pretty stuck as after hours of searching I could not find a tool that is able to accomplish this. Basically, I need some build tool that allows me to compile the templates and do other important stuff (like minification for example). I have used VITE quite a lot, but primarily for SPAs. You can still build multipage applications by specifying multiple entry points, and you can leverage templating by using the vite templating language <%= title %>, you can also tweak it using your own logic or other plugins. Unfortunately, I can't quite grasp how to solve the problem of generating multiple html files out of one and how to insert the correct translations in the different localized versions. Using vite for this purpose seems like a hack and I feel like there is some better option out there but I can't find it. Any suggestions?
